# Structure giving me "expression must be modifiable value"

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef, stdio

I am suppose to be writing a program that keeps record of payroll  to learn structs, but I find structs confusing I understand that they create a datatype and you would use -> or. to define that but I'm getting an error. 2 Questions,

1. Whats the problem?
2. The program wants me to add the ability to keep up to 1 million records, I assume this is done through an array with the EMPLOYEE structure type? Would I just send in my EMPLOYEE records variables into the EMPLOYEE array like I would any other array?

I know the "jude.name" is the problem area not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000000
typedef struct{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
}DATE;

typedef struct Employee{
    char *name[100];
    int *age;
    float *hrsWorked;
    float *regPay;
    float *otPay;
    float *totalPay;
    DATE payDate;

}EMPLOYEE;

void recordManager();
int main(){
    DATE today;
    DATE tp;
    EMPLOYEE jude;
    EMPLOYEE jp;
    jude.name = "jude";



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there specific reason you defined all members of `EMPLOYEE` (with the execption of `payDate`) to be pointers?

Comment: Try `(jude.name)[0]="Jude";`

Comment: @alk in the slides my professor provided thats how they did it, I know you can do it without pointers but right now structures are quite confusing

Comment: This would allow an employee to have 100 names ... :-)

Comment: I am trying to solve this, but it is a frustrating issue I have with this field, when I run into trouble while programming I get stuck, and I often guess you can say through a mix of anxiety and frustration reach a stall, I would be happy if some one could suggest ways that can at least make the process less frustrating, its as if I learn things but applying them is difficult :/

Comment: @alk ... but no space for even just one! ;-)

Comment: You should really go and double-check with your teacher, whether definition of the structure for an employee s/he provided was meant the way you show it to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the statement ...

```
jude.name = "jude";
```

... is that `jude.name` resolves to an array (of 100 pointers to `char`).  You can *initialize* arrays in declarations -- and that can look deceptively like an assignment -- and you can assign to array *elements*, but you cannot assign to whole arrays.

As for keeping a million records, if they must all be in memory at once (as opposed, say, to some of them being in a file) then an array of `structs` is one possible alternative:

```
EMPLOYEE employees[1000000];
unsigned employee_count = 0;
```

You can assign to `struct`s just as to any other type; the result is the same as assigning each field of the right-hand `struct` to the corresponding field of the left-hand `struct`.  For example:

```
EMPLOYEE one_employee;
/* ... initialize one_employee ... */

employees[employee_count++] = one_employee;
```

Whether an array is a sensible data structure to use, and whether this manner of assignment suits your purposes, depend on what your program is supposed to *do* with the records.

Note, too, that you probably do not want your structure members to be pointers, except possibly for `name` (in which case you would surely want just one pointer, not an array of them):

```
typedef struct Employee{
    char  name[100];
    int   age;
    float hrsWorked;
    float regPay;
    float otPay;
    float totalPay;
    DATE  payDate;
} EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: @johnbolinger I assume he wants it as a file I guess because a bonus is being able to have the program continue from where you left off, I assume you do this from a text file

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to change the base address of an array, which is not allowed in C. An array name is not a modifiable lvalue.

In your Employee declaration, you probably want to store a single name. Your current declaration is storing space for 100 character arrays. You should change it to

```
char name[100];
```

This reserves space for name to be upto 99 characters long (+1 for the terminating null character).

You can then assign name in it as below-

```
strcpy(name, "jude");
```

Comment: I don't understand how char * name is storing 100 character arrays, while char name[100] is correct, isn't the pointer just pointing to an array with a 99 char limit just like the one you  recommended?

Comment: @Jude Imagine an array of char *. And then realize that you've created one in your code.

Comment: char *name[100] is an array for 100 character pointers. Each character pointer can store a string of characters.  char name[100] is an array for 100 characters only.

Comment: Is this because the compiler reads an array as a pointer to the [0] element already and so char *name is actually a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: The data type declared before the variable name becomes the data type for the array. So you want an array of "char" and not "char *" for storing a single string.

Comment: @sray: "*Each character pointer can store a string of characters.*" This is wrong. A `char`-pointer can only **reference** ("point to") a `char`-array. It does **not provide any memory** to store the actual array (its elements) it is pointing to.

Comment: @alk Yes a character array (string of characters) may be 1 or more characters long. And i had meant that a character pointer can point to where an array of characters is stored. Or a character pointer can be malloc-ed to allocate memory for an array of characters and the pointer would be the handle to it.

Comment: @sray "*handle*" is not "*store*". Stay accurate when advising. You stated/implied fundamentaly wrong concepts.